# How to connect 2 forms in drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I have 2 forms in drupal 7 and I want to connect these 2 form.. Means when I will fill first form with some values then this form should be submit with ajax.After submit new form should be show.

Answer (score 0):

You might need [MultiStep form](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/drupal-7-ajax-driven-multi-step-forms-non-javascript-fallback) using ajax enabled. Just implement `#ajax` on the buttons of form as in the given link.

```
    $form['buttons'] = array(
      '#type' => 'container',
    );
    if($form_state['step'] !== 1) {
      $form['buttons']['back'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Back'),
        '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
        '#submit' => array('ajax_form_multistep_form_back_submit'),
        '#ajax' => array(
          // We pass in the wrapper we created at the start of the form
          'wrapper' => 'ajax_form_multistep_form',
          // We pass a callback function we will use later to render the form for the user
          'callback' => 'ajax_form_multistep_form_ajax_callback',
        ),
      );
    }
    if($form_state['step'] !== 3) {
      $form['buttons']['forward'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Next'),
        '#ajax' => array(
          'wrapper' => 'ajax_form_multistep_form',
          'callback' => 'ajax_form_multistep_form_ajax_callback',
        ),
      );
    }
    else {
      $form['buttons']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#ajax' => array(
          'wrapper' => 'ajax_form_multistep_form',
          'callback' => 'ajax_form_multistep_form_ajax_callback',
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... Can it possible without multistep form?

Comment: Ofcourse, You just need to change some logic.

Comment: can you some guide me..I am new in drupal.

Comment: Guide.. here??? I don't think it will possible without a chat?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful .. [Node Save Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_save_redirect)

> This module provides a method of specifying a location to take the
>   user after saving a piece of content.
>
> A set of radios buttons are added to the submission vertical tab on
>   the content type edit form.

Comment: Sir but I need to do this custom form using drupal module.

Comment: then use hook_node_insert() along with drupal_goto() in it.